# Unable to copy symbols from this device in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Everytime I want to lauch my app on the iPad the following error occurrs: `XCode was unable to read the required data from the device.
I've tried every solution, I found on the internet but nothing works

Comment: What  are your iPad iOS version, Xcode version, OSX/macOS version?

Comment: Delete the old build if any. Clean and run again.

Comment: iPad version: 9.3.5     OS X Version: El Capitan 10.11      I can't see my xcode version

Answer (score 3):

I think your xCode is back dated & iPad iOS version is up to date. Update xCode to get rid of this issue.

Comment: What is your xCode version ?

Comment: Goto --> Xcode ---> About Xcode to see Xcode version.